# sort string by its length

Tags: java, sorting

```
 String[] arrays = {"AA", "B"};
 Arrays.sort(arrays, (s1, s2)->s1.length()-s2.length());
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays));
```

It's my test for jdk 8 environment. When s1.length() is bigger than s2.length(), the comparator return a negative number, thus s1 is in front of s2. But the result is ["B", "AA"]. What's wrong ?

When s1.length() is bigger than s2.length(), the comparator return a **positive** number, thus s2 is in front of s1. So the result is ["B", "AA"]. I just make a foolish mistake.

Comment: Do you want to sort the string array from shortest to largest (just checking the length alone) ? Could you explain what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2):

```
o1 - object1 in your case s1
o2 - object2 in your case s2
```

compare method works and returns in this way

```
-1 : o1 < o2
0 : o1 == o2
+1 : o1 > o2
```

in your case `s1 < s2` so it returns -1 and hence it sorts in ascending  order smaller first and then bigger.

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
```

o/p

```
B
AA
[B, AA]
```

in below case if we reverse the return parameteres like below

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        return s2.length() - s1.length();
    }
```

it returns positive number hence sorts based on descending order bigger first and then smaller.

and the o/p is

```
B
AA
[AA, B]
```

now return just 0

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        return s2.length() - s2.length();
    }
```

o/p - no sorting happened as it assumes all coming objects are equal.

```
B
AA
[AA, B]
```

let me know for any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Let's modify it to log the values

```
String[] arrays = { "AA", "B" };
Arrays.sort(arrays, (s1, s2) -> {
    System.out.println("s1: " + s1);
    System.out.println("s2: " + s2);
    return s1.length() - s2.length();
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays));
```

This prints

```
s1: B
s2: AA
[B, AA]
```

`B` has a smaller length than `AA`, so

```
return s1.length() - s2.length();
```

returns a negative value. The `sort` method takes that and flips them in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is backward.  It sounds like you want to subtract s1.length() from s2.length().

Comment: When a negative number returned, s1 is in front of s2, and s1.length is bigger than s2, so I think the reuslt should be ["AA", "B"]